# SSH клиент для macOS со Snippets

Tags: macos, ssh, поиск-программ

Есть хороший клиент Termius, но он хорош для удаленных работ. В нем есть и Snippets, но они используются для авторизации и, повторюсь, авторизации на сервере.

Единственное что меня огорчает в этом клиенте - это нельзя работать на локальной машине.

Что мне нужно от клиента:

- Сохранение snippet'ов.
- Применение этих snippet'ов в любой момент.
- И все это локально.

У меня локально много разных проектов, с которыми нужно очень часто взаимодействовать. Взаимодействие происходит через терминал, отсюда куча неудобств - много специфичных команд, путей, которые порой достигают приличных размеров, чтобы их запоминать.

Есть костыль в виде заметок. Но хочется все-таки найти более приличное решение.